# using p4.net in Reporting Services 2008 R2

Tags: .net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, perforce

I am using MS SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 R2 to produce reports.

I have Perforce database where I query Changesets data and put into report. I needed to get code statistics from Perforce database but Perforce database does not have this information.

Therefore, I have written a custom DLL to get the number of codes changed in a particular changeset. Then I have created a Calculated field and called the method which calculates the number of changed code lines and passed the changeset number.

it works... however it is stupidly slow... I could not way to figure out why it is slow this much as the code calculation on the custom dll using p4.net is faily cheap job from the performance point of view.

I know it is very specific situation, but could you guys give me some idea how to find what causes the slowness?

Many thanks for your help, please ask any question for clarification.

Cheers

AnarchistGeek

Comment: Have you timed the calls you're making to P4.Net? What kind of calls are you making, and how many of them are you executing?

Comment: We need more information, e.g., how are you calculating the value? commands etc? When is the calculation being done?

Comment: Mike, Thanks for the reply. So, I make a method call for each record I retrieve from database. it is about 7000 records. This means, Reporting Services makes 7000 method calls to my custom assembly. The method in the assembly takes the changenumber as  parameter, finds the changed files and calculates the number of code changes using p4 diff2 command. I could not find any better way to calculate it more efficiently. I dont know how I can minimize the number of the calls made to dll.. Do you have idea? Thanks/

Comment: It might not be a good practice to do the calculation this way, but I needed to schedule reports via SSRS. So the pseudocode for each operation is, Run p4 Describe -s ChangesetNumber, Parse the output and find the files and revisions submitted on this changeset, run diff2 -ds filename rev-1 rev for each file on the changeset, parse the output using regular ex, return the result... Basically when I generate a report, I repeat this operation 7000 times.. that is where the slowness comes from..

Comment: Just got the figures, it took 14:08 minutes to calculate changed lines of 8000 changeset... nearly 100ms for each changeset... I will try to optimize code as much as I can, but I dont know how much further I can go... any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Are  you able to determine if the time is mostly spent on the `describe` command or the `diff2` command?  The `describe` portion could be optimized by reading the data from a relational database, if you replicate the metadata using P4toDb.

Comment: then the number of the call made to dll will increase, wont it? if we get this data from the relational database, then the number of the files we need to apply diff will increase.. I have not tested it, but this is my initial thoughts. but if find a way to use date and path in diff, that will sort the problem. then at least, I will be able to get the number of code lines changed in a particular date, which will be enough for me..

Comment: Just performed a test to find out what portion takes the most of the time. In 8000 changesets, entire operation took 14 minutes, and 10 minutes of this time taken by describe method which is nearly 70% of the time. and the 30 percent spent for diff of the 29000 files.

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion I have is to pre-calculate the change size and store them in an attribute on the file revision.  You can use the undocumented `p4 attribute` command.

```
PS> p4 help undoc

    attribute -- Set per-revision attributes on revisions (unsupported)

    p4 attribute [ -e -f -p ] -n name [ -v value ] files...

        Sets a user-managed attribute 'name' to 'value' on opened files.
        If -v isn't given the attribute is cleared (if set).

        Attributes can only be viewed with 'p4 fstat'.

        The -e flag indicates the 'value' is in hex.

        The -f flag sets the attribute on submitted files.

        The -p flag creates an attribute whose value will be propagated
        when the file is opened with 'p4 add', 'p4 edit', or 'p4 delete'.

PS> p4 help undoc

    Unsupported or obsolete Perforce commands and options:
...

    p4 fstat [ -Oacedhiz ] [ -A pattern ]
        The -Oa flag shows attributes set by 'p4 attribute'.  The -Oae flag
        shows the attribute values encoded as hex.  The -Od flag outputs the
        digest of the attribute.  The -Oc flag outputs the path, revision and
        type of the server archive file (requires 'admin' privilege). The
        -Oz flag outputs the path and revision of any lazy copies (requires
        'admin' privilege).  The -Oh flag outputs the size, digest and any
        selected attributes of the synced revision rather than the head
        revision. The -Oi flag outputs extra (debugging) information about
        the attributes.  The -A pattern flag restricts attributes to those
        matching 'pattern'.
```